# Django + Jinja2 about generated HTML

Tags: django, jinja2

The HTML code generated by Jinja2 sometimes is not well indented (checking view source in my web browser). So I was asking should I care about this?

Also, is there any style guide when working with Jinja templates?
for example indenting source code, which style is prefered?

```
<ul>
    {% for i in seq %}
    <li>{{ i }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
{% for i in seq %}
    <li>{{ i }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't be too worried about how jinja formats its HTML when you're viewing it in a browser's dev console or source code.  Having your code output in the browser with the right format is the important thing, and they have some options for [whitespace control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#whitespace-control) for that.  If the format in the source code is something you think could be an improvement to implement, then you could try talking about it with the [community](http://jinja.pocoo.org/community/).

As far as indentation style when writing jinja code, their documentation doesn't seem to have a specific guide, but they do use a fairly consistent style in their examples.  Your second example is what they seem to prefer:

```
<ul>
{% for i in seq %}
    <li>{{ i }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can see an example of them using it in their docs [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#synopsis).

Given how jinja mimics Python so closely, I tend to look to the Python style guidelines.  Really, though, the main consideration when it comes to what style you use should be readability.